# Feasible Condition with a single constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

A linear program with a single constraint minimize

$z = c_{1}x_{1} + c_{2}x_{2} +· · ·+c_{n}x_{n}$

subject to $a_{1}x_{1} + a_{2}x_{2} +· · ·+a_{n}x_{n} ≤ b$, $x_{1}, x_{2}, . . . , x_{n} ≥ 0.$

(a) Under what conditions is the problem feasible?

(b) Develop a simple rule to determine an optimal solution, if one exists

For part (a), I think only when the problem doesn't degenerate or cycle, and the basis matrix B is invertible, then the problem is feasible?

For part (b), since linear programming is always convex, only need to check it at the "corner point" or on the boundary. This occurs when one or some of $x_{i}=0$ and the remaining variables = 0. Is this rule sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is always feasible if $b \geq 0$, and is feasible for $ b < 0$  if and only if $a_i < 0$ for some $i$.  (However, if for any $a_i < 0$ and $c_i < 0$ for any $i$, z is unbounded below and thus no solution is defined.)

Comment: many thanks for your great answer Mark:) What if $b\geq 0$ but all the $a_{i} < 0$ and some of the $c_{i}<0$? Shouldn't z be unbounded too? And how about the rule? Btw, can you help me with this problem as well?

Comment: I think in any cases of $b$, we need $c_{i}$>0 corresponding to any $a_{i}$<0 to avoid the problem unbounded. Is this correct?